# My jar file runs fine in windows but in linux it throws 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException'

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, jms, ibm-mq

I am trying a prototype of Spring + IBM MQ service. I am able to successfully run and hit the message queue and get the response in windows with the jar file that is created via maven.

But once i move this jar file into a Linux box and try to hit the below command, it throws exception. Herewith attaching all the necessary information. Any help is greatly appreciated guys.!

I am stuck with with for a long time now. :-(

> Java jdk 1.7
>   Eclipse Oxygen
>
> IBM MQ 8.0.0.4 (trial version)

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mqjms</artifactId>
            <version>${webSphereMQVersion}</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.jmqi</artifactId>
            <version>${webSphereMQVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${springJMSVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${springJMSVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Successful Output i get in Windows:
[image: Successful Run in Eclipse]

exception in Linux box:

```
[pts/0][17:32:53:oracle@abcdefgh ] ~/ABC/MQQueue>java -jar springjms-0.0.1.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 6 more
```

Comment: first run jar vft springjms-0.0.1.jar | grep JMSException. Can you find this class into your jar?

Comment: Hi Alex, I am getting the below error when i try to run this command.! 

`[pts/0][17:57:46:oracle ] ~/ABC/MQQueue>jar vft springjms-0.0.1.jar  | grep JMSException
-bash: jar: command not found`

Comment: OK, this means that you do not have jar utility on your machine. So, use zip, unzip or something similar. First, be sure that class is in jar or not.

Comment: I would suggest you reference only the `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar` and stop referencing `com.ibm.mqjms` and `com.ibm.mq.jmqi`.  You will need to reference a jms 2.0 jar file as well which I think is the `javax.jms-api` you are referencing.

Comment: Hi All, made this work. the dependency-jars were missing when i tried to run the native jar file. When i added the folder, it completed successfully. Thanks for all the help.


[11:19:49:oracle] ~/ABC/MQQueue>ls -ltr
total 16
**-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall 10270 May 16 19:26 springjms-0.0.1.jar**
**drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle oinstall  4096 May 17 11:19 dependency-jars**


`[pts/0][11:19:58:oracle] ~/ABC/MQQueue>java -jar springjms-0.0.1.jar
May 17, 2019 11:20:05 AM`